# uninitialized constant Twitter (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, opensuse

Hey guys i have a problem i am facing with the twitter gem. I have a file (twitter.rb) with this content

```
require "rubygems"
require "twitter"

puts Twitter.user_timeline("roykasa").first.text
puts Twitter.user("roykasa").location
search = Twitter::Search.new
search.containing("hate").to("StewieJokess").
result_type("recent").each do |r| puts r.text end
```

When i run the file i get this error :
   uninitialized constant Twitter (NameError)
I read somewhere on SO where a user had a similar problem and he solved it by installing a new version of ruby and rubygems but the problem i am having is am running suse 12.1 and  am running the latest versions of both ruby and ruby gems. No rpms can be found from 3rd parties anywhere. Atleast i have searched. Does anyone know another way round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Ruby 1.8.x you should be able to solve your problem by renaming your own script to anything different than `twitter.rb`.

This is because the main file in the `twitter` gem is named exactly like this and your file probably overrides it in combined virtual file system that the `$LOAD_PATH` order creates. Before Ruby 1.9.x, `require` did not only load from library directories, but preferred to load files relative to the current working directory of your process, in this case, the directory where your script lies in.

Comment: No this wont help reason being i have another file called followers-location.rb which also raises the same error when i run it. And even when i run it this file line by line in the irb interpreter, i get the same error at the point where **puts Twitter.user_timeline("roykasa").first.text**

Comment: Probably because you run the `irb` command in the same working directory as the file? And the `followers-location.rb` probably lies in the same folder too. No file in your working directory should have the same relative path as any file in any gem you want to load in your script, because if you do that, it will not be loaded from the gem, but from your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do not name your file as *twitter.rb*, also make sure there is no other file in the same directory with the name *twitter.rb*